# How to set RecyclerView app:layoutManager="" from XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, androidx

How to set [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) layoutManager from XML?

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layoutManager="???"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: See documentation: [recyclerview:layoutManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#attr_android.support.v7.recyclerview:layoutManager)

Comment: @dieter_h can you provide an answer with GridLayoutManager example?

Comment: You can use `app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"`. Constructor with four arguments will be used (`Context`, `AttributeSet`, `int`, `int`). According to documentation this is the _constructor used when layout manager is set in XML by RecyclerView attribute layoutManager. If spanCount is not specified in the XML, it defaults to a single column_

Answer (score 366, accepted):

As you can check in the doc:

> Class name of the **`Layout Manager`** to be used.
>
> The class must extend `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerViewView$LayoutManager` and have either a default constructor or constructor with the signature `(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)`
>
> If the name starts with a `'.'`, application package is prefixed. Else, if the name contains a `'.'`, the classname is assumed to be a full class name. Else, the recycler view package (`androidx.appcompat.widget`) is prefixed

With **androidx** you can use:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager">
```

With the **support libraries** you can use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager" >
```

Also you can add these attributes:

- **`android:orientation`** = `"horizontal|vertical"`: to control the orientation of the LayoutManager (eg:`LinearLayoutManager`)
- **`app:spanCount`**: to set the number of columns for `GridLayoutManager`

Example:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:spanCount="2"
    ...>
```

or:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ...>
```

You can also add them using the **`tools`** namespace (i.e. `tools:orientation` and `tools:layoutManager`) and then it only impacts the IDE preview and you can continue setting those values in code.

Comment: And you can use `android:orientation` on the RecyclerView element to control the orientation of e.g. LinearLayoutManager

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti I checked the implementation and it uses reflection. Is that okay from performance wise?

Comment: As of this comment it seems the docs no longer have that useful explanation. So frustrating that @Google can't even keep their docs correct.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment I've created an [**issue ticket for it here.**](https://issuetracker.google.com/68949138)

Comment: Are there more available attributes in case I use GridLayoutManager ? Is it possible to set its number of columns (spanCount) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes, e.g. to set it to three columns use app:spanCount="3"

Comment: is there a way to define number of columns?

Comment: @nimi0112 use this app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"

Comment: Please switch to AndroidX.

Comment: you can also use `tools:layoutManager, tools:spanCount` (even though the auto-complete doesn't show it) and if you don't want to override any of your recyclerview setup (or prefer programatically)

Answer (score 95):

And I came here looking for `androidx` version though it was pretty easy to figure out, here it is

**LinearLayoutManager:**

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

**Example:**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

**GridLayoutManager:**

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
```

**Example:**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:spanCount="2"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"/>
```

As you can see in examples above you can control the orientation from within `xml` using

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

and

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

And to set the number of columns for **GridLayoutManager** using

```
app:spanCount="2"
```

Comment: You can set no. of columns when you use `GridLayoutManager` by adding `app:spanCount="2"`

Comment: future compatible approach.

Comment: Same here... Androidx about to take off 

Comment: Thanks I was looking for `spanCount` found it here. Thats why upvote to the answer :)

Answer (score 94):

if you want use it with `LinearLayoutManager`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" >
```

that equivalent to

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: What is your addition to Gabriele Mariotti answer?

Comment: explain what equivalent to in code but with anther example LinearLayout

Comment: @UdiOshi to make it horizontal, you need to add `android:orientation="horizontal"` to the RecyclerView xml

Comment: androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager for androidX

Answer (score 18):

The most common ones that I use are:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager" 
    tools:listitem="@layout/grid_item"
    android:orientation="vertical" app:spanCount="3"/>
```

And:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/grid_item"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

It's recommended to set `listitem` , so that you'd see how it could look in the preview of the layout editor.

If you want to have the order reversed though, I think you have to do it in code instead, and use "tools" in XML if you really want to see something...

Comment: which is `apps` and `app` namespaces you have used in above xml? because I am getting build time error `Android resource linking failed - AAPT: error: attribute orientation`, if I use `app:orientation`.

Comment: thanks, but still it is wrong namespace. It should be `android` for `orientation`. It doesn't work with `app` namespace everything else is perfect.

Comment: @Omkar Correct again. Sorry. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me - just add `app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"` and you're good to go

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recordItemList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:stackFromEnd="true"
        app:reverseLayout="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the layout manager for recyclerview like this,  `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"`

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    tools:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    />
```

layoutManager can be `android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager`, `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager`

[[Read more here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49320755/4770877)