# How can i set layoutmanager to RecycleView using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How can i set layoutmanager to RecycleView using kotlin as java code below:

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
```

Comment: recyclerView.layoutManager = mLinearLayoutManager

Answer (score 35):

Following two lines sets ***orientation*** to ***vertical***

```
mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL ,false)
```

OR

```
mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL ,false)
```

sets horizontal orientation

To set grid layout,

```
mRecyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, spanCount)
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context) // default orientation is vertical

// if you want horizontal recyclerview
// recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using below solution

```
val mRecyclerView= v.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rec) //id RecyclerView    
mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)
```

Answer (score 2):

Choose the layout:

- LinearLayoutManager(context). // vertical
- LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) // horizontal
- GridLayoutManager(context, numberOfColumns) // grid

Then apply the layout using Kotlin's apply() which removes repetition.

```
val rv = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
rv.apply {
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    adapter = recyclerViewAdapter()
    setHasFixedSize(true)
    ...
}
```

It can also be set in XML like this:

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

For more info see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679776/how-to-set-recyclerview-applayoutmanager-from-xml) and [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#plan-your-layout).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
linearLayoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
recyclerview!!.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
recyclerview!!.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
recyclerview!!.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

use RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL for AndroidX instead of LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL

```
var vegetableList: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list_vegetable)
            vegetableList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,
            RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write this to set `LayoutManager`

```
 // Define this globally
 lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

 // Initialize this after `activity` or `fragment` is created
 recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView

 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
 recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity!!) as RecyclerView.LayoutManager
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, reason was I had initialize recyclerView as

```
var recyclerView = findViewById<View>(R.id.recycleView)
```

Make sure you initialize as below

```
var recyclerView = findViewById<View>(R.id.recycleView) as RecyclerView
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply plugin in your app build

```
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

For my case view id of `RecyclerView` is `my_recycler_view`.

In your java file write -

```
my_recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
```

By default `LinearLayoutManager(context)` will set vertical orientation, update it as per need.

Answer (score 0):

You can set using this code:

```
binding.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this ,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL ,false)
binding.recyclerView.adapter = customAdapter(this ,getList())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
```

mRecyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Kotlin android.

Declare lateinit variable smoothScroller

```
lateinit var smoothScroller: SmoothScroller
```

Within OnCreate Mehtod Initilize the smoothScroller

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    smoothScroller = object : LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
        override fun getVerticalSnapPreference(): Int {
            return SNAP_TO_START
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, Check if the Adopter is Initialized or not?
Commit Old dataset changes if there are any.
Set the position.
Start scroller.

```
if (this@ChooseTemplate::genericAdapter.isInitialized && this@ChooseTemplate::smoothScroller.isInitialized) {
        this@ChooseTemplate.genericAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(this@ChooseTemplate.templatesrowIndex);
        dataBinding!!.rvTemplate.layoutManager!!.startSmoothScroll(this@ChooseTemplate.smoothScroller);
    }
```

dataBinding is an binding object.
rvTemplate is a Recycler View.
genericadapter is an adopter for rvTemplate.
templatesrowIndex is the index to check which row item is currently selected.

Answer (score 0):

**Handling Errors while Creating a layoutManager with recyclerView in mainActivity.kt**

-> Add  `android:id="@+id/recyclerView"`

-> In build.gradle(Module :app) add this line `id 'kotlin-android-extensions` under plugin then click on Sync Now

-> add below line in MainActivity.kt

```
val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

Answer (score -1):

`recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)`

or

`recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, spanCount)`

Comment: This answer doesn't provide move information than already given answers.