# How to change the orientation of a recycler view in xml?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 recycler views. 1 horizontal and 1 vertical. In the design page the elements for the first recycler are horizontal and for the second are vertical, but when I run then app both of them are vertical and I can't figure out what's the problem.

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/selected_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name_edit_text"
        tools:listItem="@layout/item_participant_selected" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/participants_padding_bottom"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/selected_recycler_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/selected_recycler_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/selected_recycler_view"
        tools:listItem="@layout/item_participant" />
```

Comment: Please try horizontal linear layout manager

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679776/how-to-set-recyclerview-applayoutmanager-from-xml

Answer (score 5):

Xml -

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

Programmatically -

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 2):

It can easily be done through programatically

**XML:**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/participants_padding_bottom"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/selected_recycler_view"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/selected_recycler_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/selected_recycler_view"
    tools:listItem="@layout/item_participant" />
```

**Java:**

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recycler_view.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

**Kotlin:**

```
recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Horizontal linear layout manager as I have commneted

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
= new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

since you do not set the `LayoutManager` in .xml you just should use

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```