# RecyclerView not showing the list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Can anyone help me, the problem is in the android display, why doesn't it appear, is there something wrong in my code, even though I have used recyleview correctly, can someone help me? the problem is I am so troubled why the recyleview doesn't appear on the Android screen

HomeFragment.kt

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

companion object {

    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance() =
        HomeFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                // putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount)
            }
        }
}

private lateinit var adapter: MyAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    arguments?.let {
        // columnCount = it.getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT)
    }
}


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    homeViewModel =
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    val linearLayout: LinearLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.linear_home)
    homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        linearLayout.background
    })


    return root
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    val items = listOf(
        Model("Premature optimization is the root of all evil", "blalalal", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model(
            "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.",
            "Arthur C. Clarke",
            R.drawable.film_1
        ),
        Model("Content 01", "Source", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model("Content 02", "Source", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model("Content 03", "Source", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model("Content 04", "Source", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model("Content 05", "Source", R.drawable.film_1)
    )

    adapter = MyAdapter()
    adapter.replaceItems(items)
    recylerViewFilm.adapter = adapter
}

class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private var items = listOf<Model>()


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.row_film, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]


        holder.titleTv.text = item.title
        holder.descriptionTv.text = item.desc
        holder.imageTv.setImageResource(item.image)
    }

    fun replaceItems(items: List<Model>) {
        this.items = items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    inner class ViewHolder(override val containerView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView),
        LayoutContainer


}
```

}

fragment_home.xml

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recylerViewFilm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

row_film.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTv"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageTv"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageTv"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageTv"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageTv"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/titleTv"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have not set a layoutmanager for the recyclerview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679776/how-to-set-recyclerview-applayoutmanager-from-xml

Comment: thanks for your help, now the problem is fixed