# Cannot create other layout versions

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create other types of layout (like for tablet). For example I have login_activity that has different types:
[image]
(land,tablet land, tablet port)

But when I try to create tablet layout for my regisration_activity I get this
[image]

As it says I already have particular folder, but why I can have other layouts in layout-land folder but cannot have in layout-large-land(for example)?

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it? Would appreciate you answering me.

Comment: `layout-large` already exists and you are trying to create it again which raise the exception

Comment: Yes.I know it. But why I can have the same layouts in layount-land folder but not in other folders? And then how can I create tablet variations for registration_activity if studio doesn't allow me?

Answer (score 0):

i try to do your job and i have no your problem.
forget it.
you should use standard name for folder and handle different screen size.
check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24074396/9019611) or [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) and use standard name for folders to handle screen size.